# Broken Button CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Working button]

For some reason, I have a button that is supposed to look like the image supplied here, but on another page it doesn't look the same at all, even though it is using the same exact code. I have no idea why it doesn't work - it's gray on one page and green on another - but it's only like this in IE8 and works fine in chrome.

HTML:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="greenbutton"/>
```

CSS:

```
#greenbutton {
margin-top: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #689324;
line-height: 35px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #c1ed9c;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #92CA44), color-stop(1, #72A332) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #92CA44 5%, #72A332 100% );
background: 92ca44;
border-radius: 3px;
}

#greenbutton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #8cb82b), color-stop(1, #9dce2c) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #8cb82b 5%, #9dce2c 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8cb82b', endColorstr='#9dce2c');
background-color:#8cb82b;
}

#greenbutton:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
```

Comment: "Only in IE8" is a whole 'nother can of worms but, without being able to view both pages, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Forgot the hash tag in front of the color code. Oopsie.

Answer (score 0):

Please add # tag along with the color code in #greenbutton.

```
#greenbutton {
background: #92ca44;}
```